# How to parse data inside CDATA in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a xml like below and i have to parse the username and password inside CDATA please say how to parse it.

```
<myxml>
 <header>
  <sessionid>12245834454835486</sessionid>
 </header>
 <custommessage>
  <![CDATA[<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
  <data>
   <users>
    <username>yyy</username>
    <password>xxx</password>
   </users>
 </data>]]>
 </custommessage>
</myxml>
```

Comment: What did you try? What do you use for xml parsing?

Comment: I got the above responce from the webservice i need to parse the xml and get the value of username and password inside the respective tags.

Comment: Ready any tutorial on parsing xml. E.g. this one: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ First you need to parse outer xml, then get `<custommessage>` content as string and parse it again. Then get `username` and `password`.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your inner xml with any parser, here I will use JAXB:

```
public class Test {
    public String custommessage;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("test.xml"), Test.class);
        String xml = t.custommessage.trim();
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

this is your inner xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
  <data>
   <users>
    <username>yyy</username>
    <password>xxx</password>
   </users>
 </data>
```

now you can parse it and get your username and pwd